# Can I configure Google Play to see App Reviews in several languages?

Tags: google-play-store

By default Google Play is configured to display reviews only in my native language (not english). But there are a lot of reviews in other languages, especially in english and I want to see them also. As a workaround I can change language to english but it is not perfect solution. Can I see reviews both in my native language and in english?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not with the regular Playstore app, AFAIK. <s>If you want to do so using an app, you might want to take a look at [Market Comments Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bh.android.MarketCommentsReader). From within the web browser, [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/) allows to show comments of all languages at once, i.e. without selecting each language separately.</s>

**Update:** note that both, the app and the AndroidPIT site section, are dead by now. For a work-around you could use my UserScript [GooglePlaySwitchLang](https://greasyfork.org/de/scripts/28036-googleplayswitchlang) in a web browser (like Firefox) via an Addon like *Greasemonkey* (see the [Greasyfor main page](https://greasyfork.org/) for a list of options for your favorite browser). The script injects links to easily toggle between languages – currently German and English, but you easily can adjust it to any language combination you need.

Answer (score 23):

If You browse Play store via a web browser, then you can add `&hl=en` at the end of the URL and it may show English comments.

Comment: Not working for this page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.kingsoft.officekey&hl=en or this page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magazin.weekly&hl=en

Comment: Did work for me. @Firelord maybe these apps didn't have english reviews?

Comment: Perfectly simple & working!

Comment: Worked for me with `&hl=hu` also (for Hungarian)

Comment: This should be the main answer and the script option should be the secondary answer for advanced and motivated users.